# how to turn off sleep during active ssh connections in windows

Tags: windows, sleep, openssh

My windows pc will go to sleep after its inactivity timer has run up, apparently active ssh connections do not count towards "activity", so it will go to sleep while I'm running commands on an ssh connection. Is there a way to make windows respect ssh connections as activity?

Comment: Try Microsoft Power Toys and use the Awake Function. That may help.

Comment: Alternatively, I could maybe turn off the sleep timer on the start of an ssh connection, and turn it on again when the connection terminates. That would require running a command when a connection terminates, which perhaps is a separate question.

Comment: @John That is a good idea, but I would like to use sleep outside of this problem to keep power usage down when the pc is not in use. I saw Awake can be accessed via cli, so perhaps I could run that on ssh disconnection?

Comment: From what I can see you would need to try running Power Toys by Auto Hot Key to get a command line function.

Comment: I don't have the time to write the script at the moment, but here is a solution (I'll come back to this in the future to add as answer if there isn't anything in the meantime) I'll add a powershell script to startup so it runs at login, it'll either use powertoys awake or Powercfg to manage standby timeout depending on openssh connect/disconnect events which it can read via Get-WinEvent. That way I don't lose sleep functionality, but I can keep it awake during ssh connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I created the script, it's pretty short actually. all in all it checks if the last informational message from the openssh server was a disconnection, in which case it resets the sleep timeout to a default value, otherwise it disables sleep.

```ps
$startDate = $(Get-Date)


$interval = 10
$standby_timeout = 30

Write-Host "starting script at $startDate"

while ($true) {
    $last_event_disconnect = Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 OpenSSH/Operational | where {$_.TimeCreated -gt $startDate} | ForEach-Object {$_.message} | Select-String -Quiet "[Dd]isconnect"

    if ($last_event_disconnect) {
        Write-Host "found disconnect event, resetting to standard timeout."
        Powercfg.exe /Change standby-timeout-ac 30
    } else {
        Write-Host "there may be an ssh connection, refusing sleep."
        Powercfg.exe /Change standby-timeout-ac 0
    }

    Start-Sleep $interval
}
```

I now just run that at startup (perhaps with a stdout to logfile) You could imagine extending it easily with more sleep/nosleep conditions and a more robust check. `Powercfg.exe` should be available natively, so this doens't require any installs.

Note: I believe this does require sshd to have a logging level of INFO: add this to
`C:/ProgramData/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
LogLevel INFO
```

Comment: I mean it now doesn't sleep until there has been at least one connection, which is fine for my purposes but is a bit janky, adapt as needed. I'm accepting this as it is as far as I know a good answer to the question, and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the computer from sleeping, you could use a program such as
[Caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/)
or
[Insomnia](https://dlaa.me/Insomnia/).

Caffeine works by simulating a harmless key-press once every 59 seconds,
while  Insomnia calls an API function to disable sleep mode while
it's running.

Both programs seems to be harmless with almost no impact on your usage
of the computer, so you can keep them running in parallel with your
working (or not) as long as ssh is being used.

Comment: Insomnia seems interesting! Ultimately for a personal computer these tools don't seem necessary though: Since I have full control I can also run `Powercfg.exe /Change standby-timeout-ac 0|xx` to turn sleep on/off. It's only the modification of staying on during ssh connections that I want.

Comment: How do you identify the ssh process when running - let me know either the `.exe` or window title. And is the protection against sleep to be maintained when the SSH window is not active?

Comment: It's a server (I use the OpenSSH.Server, see [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui), so the process will be running always. I think the best way to solve this is with a little program that taps into openSSH's events with `Get-WinEvent` and then toggles Insomnia/Caffeine/Powercfg call/etc when it sees a connect/disconnect event. I'll program it up shortly and post it. I was hoping there was like an option in the settings of the openssh server or perhaps windows itself so I wouldn't have to.